# JAVASCRIPT: Determining path depending on two selections

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have been tasked with cleaning up some code / possibly creating a more efficient route of going about the following:

There are two select boxes in a form. One called **Program Type** and the other called **Role**. There are 4 program types and 10 roles. Depending on which two you have selected, it will bring you two a certain page.

Also, certain roles **are not** selectable, depending on the program type selected. So, for instance, if "GST" was selected under Program Type - "Issue Creator", "Officer" and "Manager" would not be selectable as a role.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on what sort of JavaScript function I could use to go about this task.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a specific question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions or directions are off-topic.

Comment: The gentleman or lady below understood my question perfectly, and answered it exactly how I wanted and expected it to be answered. I needed some guidance for inspiration - thanks for your fantastic input though.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my solution. I tend not to favour switch statements because they can become cumbersome, so I used a regular expression instead.

The code below calls the dependency function whenever the `program-type` select's value is changed. It then iterates through each option of the `role` select element, checking the current value of the `program-type` select element against each option's data-dependency attribute.

The regular expression checks if the attribute matches either the value, one of the values (separated by commas) or a catch all (which I've made `*` in this case) - so as an example, if the first option was selected for the `program-type`, the regex comparison would compute to something like:

```
"1".match(/\*|1/i) // true
"2,3".match(/\*|1/i) // false
"*".match(/\*|1/i) // true
```

If they don't match, I've set the option's display to none - but you could just disable it if you prefer...anything you want really.

If you're new to regular expressions, I'd recommend [regexr](http://regexr.com/)

Hope this helps.

```js
function dependency(e){
  var roles = document.querySelectorAll('#role option')
  for(var i = 0 ; i < roles.length ; i++) {
    var re = new RegExp('\\*|' + e.currentTarget.value, 'i')
    if(roles[i].dataset.dependency.match(re)) roles[i].style.display = 'block'
    else roles[i].style.display = 'none'
  }
}

document.querySelector('#program-type').addEventListener('change', function(e){
  dependency(e)
})
```

```html
<select id="program-type" name="program-type">
  <option value="default" disabled selected>Select Program-Type</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>  
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select id="role" name="role">
  <option value="foo" data-dependency="*" disabled selected>Select role</option>  
  <option value="foo" data-dependency="1">foo</option>  
  <option value="bar" data-dependency="2,3">bar</option>  
  <option value="baz" data-dependency="*">baz</option>  
</select>
```

Comment: This is great! I haven't had the opportunity to test it out, but it seems quite promising and just what I was looking for. Thanks for the prompt reply!

Comment: I'm not quite sure how/that I understand how to adjust the values in the data-dependency with more options than you provided. For instance: